# Show a custom post title in another custom post type in Meta box

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, metabox

I have created two custom post type. Suppose A and B.

I would like to fetch A custom post title in B in meta box in a drop-down.

I am not getting any solution.

Is anybody help me to find the solution.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get all the titles of **CPT** (`Custom Post Type`) `A`, and loop through them in the second **CPT** in a metabox of CPT `B`.
Example :

```
$my_titles = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type' // get the type of your CPT
);
```

Now in your second custom post type i.e `B`, inside the `meta box` loop through them like

```
    <select name="" id="">
        <?php foreach ($my_titles as $key => $title): ?>
            <option value=""><?php echo $title; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
```